# Cannot find reason for Redundant nullcheck of this, which is known to be non-null

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

In Sonar I see a Redundant nullcheck of this, which is known to be non-null Error, but I can not find the Reason for this.

[image: Sonar image]

Hope somone can help me to find the reason.

Thx & Regards

Edit1:

```
    public class Filter extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Serializable {
    public Filter() {
        super();
    }
}
```

AbstractBaseEntity  has no implemented constructor

Comment: Do you check against null anywhere?

Comment: Just once: if (eachFilter != null), but removing this doesn't resolve this issue

Comment: What does the super constructor look like?

Comment: The constructor calls super() again, the calling class extends an abstract class without implemented constructor and implements serializable

Comment: If this really is everything, I'd consider a false positive...

Comment: As this is a findbugs rule and findbugs rely on bytecode, I would have a look at the .class you are providing to the analyzer. Is it modified in some way by a tool ? (AspectJ, powerMockito... )

Comment: Is there a nullcheck in `AbstractBaseEntity` constructor?

Comment: AbstractBaseEntity has no implemented constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code producing this was generated by AspectJ so it was not visible for me, but visible for sonar...